# Xampp localhost not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, xampp, localhost

I am running laravel on xampp and I have problem with accessing pages,
`http://localhost/laravel/public/` I get a login page which is good
however when I go for example `http://localhost/laravel/public/smokeyard`

I get `404` error with `The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Route:

```
Route::get('smokeyard', 'GuzzleController@smokeyard');
```

Controller:

```
function smokeyard(){
    return view('smokeyard');
}
```

All my views are located in resources folder.

Comment: 1. Check apache mod_rewrite is enabled.
2. From cmd go to your project folder. run - php artisan serve command and run your local env on http://localhost:8000 - your all routes will work
3. use :  public/index.php/<your_route>.

Comment: if you use php artisan serve does it still use mysql module from xampp?

Comment: Yes mysql and artisan doesn't any connection.

Comment: The laravel router won't work that way. You need to create a virtual host in which the root would be `http://myvhost/` . Then you can access your routes via e.g. `http://myvhost/smokeyard`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to access laravel project without running `artisan serve`, you need to change few settings,

1. copy the `.htaccess` file from the `public folder` and `paste` it in the `root folder` of your `application`
2. `rename` the `server.php` in the `root directory to index.php`

now go to `localhost/your_project_name/smokeyard` for the url you want to check

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Run `php artisan serve` and access your server at `http://localhost:8000`. Your routes should work fine then.

You can't access your laravel application routes straight away through the folder structure with xampp. You need to setup the web root to point to the `public` folder and access `localhost` or run the laravel server and use it. This is because the url rewriting would fail when you access the routes in laravel the way you do.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in MX Linux 21.xx. My xampp got messed up after installing larvel on it.

1. check MySQL status with command

```
mysql service status
```

2. stop the service using the command

```
service mysql stop
```

3. you will be prompted to provide your password, Enter password.
4. start xampp using command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

5. All should be back to normal